# Access host machine port from Hyper-V guest OS

Tags: networking, hyper-v, hypervisor

I run Windows Azure Compute Emulator on my Windows 8 PC. It's essentially a web server (it hosts my web app) and it listens on 127.0.0.1 port 80.  It doesn't listen for external requests at all and it cannot.

For the purposes of IE8 testing, I would like to run Windows XP / IE8 as a guest inside Hyper-V.

However, Hyper-V seems to give the guest OS it's own network IP as if it's an external machine.  I cannot access 127.0.0.1 of the host machine.

Any thoughts on how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use PJS PassPort.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pjs-passport/
Very easy. Remember to run it as administrator.